# Hello im new to all this and in not sure how to figure things out

Tags: transactions, tokens, uniswap, accounts

Yesterday I started the day with 16k in my saitama inu account, I was swamping saitama for ETH on uni swamp, I was swamping 7800 so it sent me back to my trust wallet to approve it so once i hit confirm it’s like the screen was froze it allowed me to go back to uni swamp only to see the circle still spinning so I went back to trust wallet and the confirm page was up and still froze so I closed the page so at that point I looked up on YouTube that I can transfer from Saitama to ETH right on my trust wallet so I did that and I was able to transfer that amount out to my Binance.US wallet 7800 that transaction went through, but somehow the first transaction that was done on uni swamp did not go through and my balance on my saitama is 1k something is not right please help with any suggestions you may have thank you!

Comment: Hi MahdyRobinson! Welcome to Ethereum Stackexchage! Do you have a the transaction hashes? Without more details there isn't much we can say.

Comment: Yes I do here are the transaction hashes in order as I did them…  the first was a purchase to buy ETH on trust wallet…2nd was the uni swamp transaction and the third was a swamp that was done on trust wallet directly and the fourth was what I sent out to my Binance.US account. 

0x7d7927b4799d35823670c5b7c2264c044176d8c857638072874c736d776e05d5


0x4268adfcc4da937a8b62a3cc2082068fd4b8b39eb472563c3a06b672104b7907

0x6c9d15456147d43afe2b850178a28e2d6193cefa7a97fddb8750716f56c34b2a

0x014d063fa52305c5099625af6521eaf1a3951de186a384f64c74c4bf328d0c30

Comment: In this tx [0x6c9d15](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x6c9d15456147d43afe2b850178a28e2d6193cefa7a97fddb8750716f56c34b2a) 10K saitama were swapped for 7.7k eth (I'd guess because saitama is a fee on transfer token). Then this tx [0x4268ad](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x4268adfcc4da937a8b62a3cc2082068fd4b8b39eb472563c3a06b672104b7907) sent 10k saitama to the address [0xa30ec52](0xa30ec5210b328ee2697f91df261084b0f5dcfc48).

Comment: Could you format your question so that there is more than one sentance and one paragraph ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.